# Proper git structure for serverless functions with heavily shared code

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I am writing multiple Google Cloud Functions (you can assume this is any serverless technology) which heavily share code. How do i structure my repository to make it clean?

I am using Python. Right now each function is having a copy of the shared module in a separate directory. I am thinking towards making two repos: a repo with the main module and a repo with the functions. Functions will contain multiple copies of git submodule pointing to the main repo.

Right now the structure is the following

```
application/
     module/
     functions/
          f1/
               module/
          f2/
               module/
```

`module/` is copied using bash script from `application/module/`

I am thinking about making `module/` directories point to git submodule. Would that be a nice solution or may be there is some better way to do that?

I want to make the code as clean as possible without sticks like bash script copying the code.

One more important point is that ideally, i would like to copy not the whole `module/` structure, but some parts of it. Every function is relying on the same parts of the main module.